# How do I find a user by DisplayName in one CSV file given a DistinguishedName is another CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv, match, relationship, matching

I have two CSV files with tab-separated values.

CSV1:

```
GivenName   Surname DisplayName  Manager    
John        Smith   John Smith   Oliver Twist
```

CSV2:

```
SAMAccountName    mail             DistinguishedName
John Smith      johns@example.com   CN=John Smith,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
Oliver Twist    olivert@example.com CN=Oliver Twist,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
```

What I've wanted to do is to compare the CSV1 with CSV2 and match the manager name in `Manager` column in CSV1 file with CSV2 `DistinguishedName` column value (i.e. `"CN=Oliver Twist"`) as in this example and export to a new CSV file like this:

```
SAMAccountName    mail              Manager
John Smith        johns@example.com Oliver Twist
```

There might be hundreds of distinguished names in CSV2 file as mentioned and all I want is output from comparing and matching the `DistinguishedName` column value `"CN=whatever name "` with the `Manager` column in CSV1.

Here is the script I tried:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path 'C:temp\AD.csv'
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\AD_ExportDN.csv'

$csv3 = foreach ($record in $csv2) {
    $matchingRecord = $csv1 | Where-Object { $_.manager -eq $record.manager }
    # if your goal is to ONLY export records with a matching email address,
    # uncomment the if ($matchingRecord) condition

    #if ($matchingRecord) {
        $record | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'manager'; Expression = {$matchingRecord.DistinguishedName}}
    #}
}

$csv3 | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Force -Path 'C:\temp\merged_for_AD2.csv'
```

Comment: Where is the code you need help with? Post what you’ve tried and include any errors or pertinent details.

Comment: Are these tab-separated values?  Or fixed-width columns?  Otherwise, that several columns contain spaces will make parsing more difficult.  Also, how are the `John Smith` entries in both tables related?  That `CSV1.DisplayName == CSV2.SAMAccountName` seems like the only way, in which case why can't the `Manager` be found via `SAMAccountName`, too, instead of `DistinguishedName`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question inspired me to add an new feature to the [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) I am maintaining (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)).
The feature is explained in issue: [`#29` key expressions](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object/issues/29).

In your case the required command will be something like:

```
$Csv1 |Join $Csv2 -On Manager -Equals { [RegEx]::Match($_.DistinguishedName, '(?<=CN=).*(?=,CN=Users)') }
```

Which returns:

```
GivenName         : John
Surname           : Smith
DisplayName       : John Smith
Manager           : Oliver Twist
SAMAccountName    : Oliver Twist
mail              : olivert@example.com
DistinguishedName : CN=Oliver Twist,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
```

For the specific regular expression `'(?<=CN=).*(?=,CN=Users)'`:

- `.*` refers to any sequence of characters that is

  - Preceded by `CN=` (`(?<=CN=)`, [regex Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))
  - and followed by `CN=Users` (`(?=,CN=Users)`, regex lookahead)